# Does the upgrade adapter support ngModel?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm looking into using Angular 2's UpgradeAdapter in order to transition my library. Many of my directives use ngModel to communicate with the consumer, but I do not see anything in the documentation or code to support upgrading this kind of component.

Is there a way to upgrade an Angular 1 directive that uses ngModel?

For instance, I have a directive:

```
module.directive('myTextbox', function() {
  return {
    template: '<input type="text"></input>',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        elem.find('input').val(ngModel.$viewValue);
      }

      elem.find('input').on('change', function(e) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(e.target.value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

in my angular 1 app I consume it by doing:

`<my-textbox ng-model="textboxValue">`

However when I upgrade `myTextbox` using `upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('myTextbox')`, as expected I get an `Error: Can not locate 'ngModel'`

Comment: You've really got two different questions here. First, the UpgradeAdapter runs v1.X and v2 at the same time. So yes it supports anything that runs in either version. It doesn't actually upgrade anything for you. As for upgrading a directive, it looks like you just need to convert it to a component directive. But that's on you to do.

Comment: @MatthewGreen I understand all of that, however my question is specifically about ngModel. In Angular 1 ngModel is an attribute directive, which doesn't appear to be upgradable. But as ngModel is such a core directive, I was hoping that there was support for it when upgrading directives.

Comment: That doesn't look like the same question above then. You might be better helped if you update your question with more information. Maybe an example of what you have and how you are trying to upgrade it. For what it's worth, [I don't see that ngModel can't be used](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgModel-directive.html).

Comment: I guess I need to do a better job of explaining that I am trying to use UpgradeAdapter to upgrade angular 1 directives that use the angular 1 ngModel. Your link is to angular 2's ngModel which is not related to my question in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to figure this out myself and the answer isn't straightforward. You can follow this up at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8314#issuecomment-229391970.

One work-around is to *create a ng1 wrapper over the ng1 component* and then ngupgrade the wrapper. This wrapper will not use ngModel, it just simply pass all parameters to the original ng1 directive, without doing other things.

For Example:

n1 directive:

```
 angular.module('components')
  .directive('checkboxes', function () {
      return {
        'require': 'ngModel',
        'restrict': 'E',
        'scope': {
          'model': '=ngModel',
          'name': '=?',
          'options': '=',
          'settings': '=?'
        },
        'templateUrl': 'app/components/forms/checkboxes/checkboxes.html',
        'controller': function ($scope) {
      }};});
```

And the wrapper:

```
  angular.module('components')
      .directive('checkboxesWrapper', function () {
          return {
            'restrict': 'E',
            'scope': {
              'model': '=',
              'name': '=?',
              'options': '=',
              'settings': '=?'
            },
            'template': '<checkboxes ng-model="model" name="name" options="options" settings="settings"></checkboxes>',
            'controller': function ($scope) {
          }};});

UpgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('checkboxesWrapper')
```

The important thing to note is **ng-model="model"**

Then in your ng2 component you can use the **banana** [()]. But again i am not sure how correctly it will work with form-controls. Let me know if you figure out more.